# How to cancel a non iterative BackGroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a non iterative code inside a BackGroundWorker, so I can´t check if CancellationPendig.

The code is the following.

```
Private Sub BgW1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgW1.DoWork
        Try
            Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.MySQL_Cnn_Cfg)
            Dim Adp As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim TablaDatos As New DataTable

            conn.Open()

            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = conn

                cmd.CommandText = e.Argument

                Adp.SelectCommand = cmd

                TablaDatos.Clear()
                Adp.Fill(TablaDatos)

                e.Result = TablaDatos
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            e.Result = "Error!"
            e.Cancel = True
        End Try
End Sub
```

The BackGroundWorker receives a query string and return a DataTable and it works if the remote server make a fast answer, but with complex querys that take some time I cant' cancel the process, or at least I don't know how.

I already try

```
BgW1.Dispose()
```

With no success, so There's another way to stop a BackGroundWorker?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to stop this code, other than by terminating your program.  If this is really important then make smaller queries that you execute one after another.  Now you can check CancellationPending.  And of course keep in mind that you are doing this for a human.  He won't like looking at *thousands* of query results either.  Make your UI usable and your code will benefit as well.

Comment: You can define a timeout for the query, and catch the exception

Comment: The DataTable is not checket by a human bean cause it must be processed and then the program generate a report to send to the customer. @SysDragon: I can't define a timeout cause I don't care how many time the query takes but if the user want to abort/Cancel the process because i.e. He must to go home or make some change in the query to make it simpler he can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot.

The only way I can see this working is if you have the `ID` of the `MySQL` connection, and another button that when you click it kills that process, in that sense the query would stop and the backgrounworker would finish.

Comment: How I can get that Id?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id

Comment: so if you open the connection, assing a variable the connection id, then execute  a sql statement outside of the backgroundworker that simply kill process (id number)

Comment: Maybe its even a better choise to use, "kill query thread_id" ,  then the connection stays intact but kills current query.

Comment: Ok great, glad i could help!